# React JS how to pass values between pages using session storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, session-storage

I have a react JS login page that accepts the user name and password. Upon entering the user name and and password, the credentials are processed against a json (API) file, which generates a token for the client. **My goal** is to pass the token to a landing page after the client has logged in and populate a dropdown list with the clients respective data. **The problem** I am facing is getting the clients token to pass from my login page to the landing page.

In my login page, I am using Fetch to retrieve the token from the API and then store the token using session-storage. The code snippet for getting the token:

```
componentDidMount() {  
        this.fetchData(); 
    } 

    //request the token
    fetchData() {
        return fetch('http://myapiaut:1111/api/auth', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
            },
             body: JSON.stringify({
                username: 'myAdminusername',
                password: 'myAdminPassword',
                Authorization: 'myAdminPassword',
            })
        }) /*end fetch */
        .then(results => results.json())
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({ data: data })
            sessionStorage.setItem("token", data)
          })
        }

      //authenticate request
      requestUserInfo() {
        var token = sessionStorage.getItem("token");
        return fetch('http://myapiaut:1111/api/auth', {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: new Headers({
            Authorization: 'Bearer' + sessionStorage.token
          }),
        })
          .then((response) => response.json());
      }
```

**Landing page**

```
componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://myapiclients:22222/api/clients', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.token
            },
        })
        .then(results => results.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ data: data }))
    }
```

...going back to the login page, I confirmed that I'm getting the token via fetchData function, **but the problem I am encountering is properly storing the token so that it may be passed to the landing page**.

FYI- I've already built the **landing page** and it functions properly when I manually copy the generated token into the Authorization section of the Fetch.
...Could, I please get some help as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does the token get stored to session storage?

Comment: Is login and landing on different domains? if not, why not use `sessionStorage.getItem` like you did before?

Comment: @Boy With Silver Wings - no and that is what am struggling with (getting the token stored within the session storage) ...I reviewed my syntax, but cannot seem to discover why the token is not getting stored. In the Login page snippet, I attempted a console.log to see if the token is being capture, but I got a message indicating the it was unreachable (on the line where I wrote on console.log). Am I implementing the console.log (please see function requestUserInfo) in the right section? Please let me know if you have any suggestions, I'm still kind of new to  React. both page (same domain )

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here:

> ```
> .then(data => this.setState({ data: data }))
> .then(data => sessionStorage.setItem('token', data))
> ```

`setState` doesn't resolve a `Promise` so it does not have `then()`

Change it to something like:

```
.then(data => {
  this.setState({ data: data })
  sessionStorage.setItem('token', data)
})
```

In landing page:

> ```
> componentDidMount() {
>         fetch('http://myapiclients/api/clients', {
>             method: 'GET',
>             headers: {
>                 'Content-type': 'application/json',
>                 'Authorization': 'Bearer ${token}'  // token is not defined!
>             },
>         })
>         .then(results => results.json())
>         .then(data => this.setState({ data: data }))
>     }
> ```

token is not defined, so it will be 'Bearer undefined', either define it before `fetch(...)` with `sessionStorage.getItem("token")` or in fetch headers do something like:

```
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.token
```